# Infinity scroll bug with data template

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

After user get the end of longlistselector `ItemRealized` event fires items add successfully. But the button's tag is empty (for added items), for items that I got first time button's tag isn't null.

This is my xaml `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TitleSongDataTemplate" x:Name="Titledata">
        <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Margin="0,0,12,12">
            <Grid  x:Name="GridOfButtons" Background="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" >
                <Grid Margin="0, -6, -7, 0"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="83">
                    <Button 
                        Content="&#xe109;" 
                        FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" 
                        Style="{StaticResource RoundButton}" 
                        x:Name="AddToMySongsButton"
                        Tag="{Binding Song}"
                        Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"
                        Click="AddToMySongsButton_Click"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid                          
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Margin="-17,-6,0,0" Height="81" Width="95">
                    <Button FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"                             
                        Content="&#xe102;"
                        Style="{StaticResource RoundButton}" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                        x:Name="PlayButton"                            
                        Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"
                        Tag="{Binding Song}"                            
                        Click="PlayButton_Click"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Margin="69,-7,60,0" Height="82" Width="84">
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundButton}"
                        Content="&#xe118;" 
                        FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
                        x:Name="DownloadButton"                            
                         Margin="-5,0,0,0"
                         Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"
                        Tag="{Binding Song}"
                        Click="DownloadButton_Click"/>
                </Grid>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" Margin="6 , 4, 6, 4"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}" Foreground="Gray" Opacity="0.75" Margin="6, 0, 0, 6"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

My pivot:

```
<phone:Pivot x:Name="MainTitle">            
        <phone:PivotItem Header="Rock">
            <Grid>
                <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="RockLongList"
                    GridCellSize="220,150"
                LayoutMode="Grid"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TitleSongDataTemplate}"
                ItemRealized="RockLongList_ItemRealized"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="RockText"
                           Text="Загрузка..." 
                           FontSize="60"
                           Opacity="0.5"
                           Style="{StaticResource LongListSelectorGroupHeaderLetterTileStyle}" 
                           Margin="0,10,10,10"                               
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                           Width="436"/>
            </Grid>
        </phone:PivotItem>
```

Here my infinity scrooling realization:

1.I fired ItemRealized

```
private void RockLongList_ItemRealized(object sender, ItemRealizationEventArgs e)
    {
        var nownum = offset + 50;
        if (nownum >= usercount)
        {
            MainTitle.Title = "All songs've downloaded";
        }
        else
        {
            SpecialSongs.SongJSON song = e.Container.Content as SpecialSongs.SongJSON;
            if (song != null)
            {
                int myoffset = 2;
                // Only if there is no data that is currently getting loaded would be initiate the loading again
                if (!isCurrentlyLoading && defaultBindList.Count - defaultBindList.IndexOf(song) <= myoffset)
                {
                    LoadDataFromSource();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally:

```
private void LoadDataFromSource()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            MainTitle.Title = "Downloading test...";
        });
        //progressBar.IsVisible = true;
        isCurrentlyLoading = true;
        string UsersUri = string.Format("https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?&count=50&access_token={0}&user_id={1}&version=4.92&offset={2}", AccessToken, uID, offset);
        //var query = string.Format(datasourceUrl, currentPage);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(UsersUri));
    }

    private void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Here handle exception
        using (var reader = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(e.Result)))
        {
            SpecialSongs songs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SpecialSongs>(e.Result);
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                foreach (var tracks in songs.songs)
                {
                    rockBindList.Add(tracks);                        
                    MainTitle.Title = "Downloaded test...";
                }
                RockLongList.ItemsSource = rockBindList;
                isCurrentlyLoading = false;
                //progressBar.IsVisible = false;
            });
          }
          offset += 50;
      }
```

This code shows why i need button's tag property:

```
private void DownloadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SpecialSongs.SongJSON songdgd = (SpecialSongs.SongJSON)(sender as Button).Tag;
            this.Download.Message = songdgd.Artist + "\n" + songdgd.Title;
            string StringToSave = "shared/transfers/" + songdgd.Artist + songdgd.Title;
            var linktosave = StringToSave.Replace(" ", "");
            transferRequest = new BackgroundTransferRequest(new Uri(songdgd.URI, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) { Method = "GET" };
            var uri = new Uri(linktosave, UriKind.Relative);
            songdgd.URI = linktosave.Replace("shared/transfers/", "");
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(songdgd);
            var name = linktosave.Replace("shared/transfers/", "");
            transferRequest.Tag = "json" + json + "json" + "uri" + name + "uri";
            transferRequest.TransferPreferences = TransferPreferences.AllowCellularAndBattery;
            transferRequest.DownloadLocation = uri;
            try
            {
                BackgroundTransferService.Add(transferRequest);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Эта песня уже загружается.");
            }
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("Error while downloading"); }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: The tag may have not set by this time.  Try using the Dispatcher to put off the code that needs the tag until later.  The DispatcherPriority should be placed lower than DataBind.

Comment: I'm sorry, i have fixed that bug. Thanks.

Comment: You should add details in an answer. You'll be able to close this out.